# Google Chrome shows “Get @username's tweets emailed to you” and Mozilla doesn’t

Tags: twitter, google-chrome, firefox

Google Chrome shows `Get @username's tweets emailed to you` when we visit the URL `https://twitter.com/username` without logging.

But this option is not shown in Mozilla Firefox. Is there a way to hide this in Google Chrome via username's account settings?

Or is the option showing up just because of some Google extensions? No Google extesnion is installed.

- Google Chrome version is *Version 20.0.1132.17 beta*
- Mozilla Version is *Version 10.0.2*

Below is a Chrome screenshot:

[image: This is chrome screen shot]

Below is a Mozilla screenshot:

[image: This is mozilla screen shot]

Although it’s not my profile, it’s showing the same on my profile.

Comment: Where do you have that option in Chrome? Can you please post a screenshot?

Comment: yeah sure, will add to question

Comment: added pls check..

Comment: Just verifying, I'm using Chromium and it doesn't show up here.

Comment: i noticed it today and googled for it but didnt find anything

Comment: It can just be a new, unreleased-for-the-public feature that is being tested on a subset of users.

Comment: may be but why on chrome and not mozilla?

Comment: I don't see that message in Chrome either. It could be random or country specific. Do you still see it?

Comment: not showing today.....wondering!!! See the attached images